# How to handle multiple approvals using Outlook Actionable Messages with Adaptive Cards in Power Automate?

Tags: azure-devops, powerapps, power-automate, adaptive-cards

I have designed an **Outlook Actionable Message using Adaptive Card** for approvals. I am sending it to 3 approvers for review and approvals via **Power Automate**.

There are 2 power automate flows created. One to send email and other to handle response from the email.

I want to update the custom field in Azure DevOps - user story after all 3 reviewers approves it.

**How can I ensure 'Everyone must approve' feature similar to 'Approvals' in Power Automate with Outlook Actionable Messages ??**

Please Note: I do not want to use the existing 'Approval' task in Power Automate.

[image]